# Net name different from defined one

Tags: altium

In [Altium Designer 18.0.8](https://www.altium.com/) I am working on some power supply:
[image: Power Supply]
As you can see, there is a [wire](https://www.altium.com/documentation/18.0/display/ADES/Sch_Obj-Wire((Wire))_AD) named `GRETZ_OUT` using [Wire command](https://www.altium.com/documentation/18.0/display/ADES/Sch_Obj-Wire((Wire))_AD) and if I hover on it with mouse, I get net name `GND` and **NOT** `GRETZ_OUT`, which is wrong:
[image: Hover]
Why?

Comment: That net is crossing two wires of the GND net. It is possible they are connected where they are crossing although I don't see a dot indicating a connection. It is also possible when you placed GND net name near those crossing you attached it to the wrong net.

Comment: @EE_socal there is no junction between `GRETZ_OUT` and `GND`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh, there was no junction between `GRETZ_OUT` and `GND`, however, [Net Label](https://www.altium.com/documentation/18.0/display/ADES/Sch_Obj-NetLabel((Net+Label))_AD) `GND` was **PLACED** on the crossing (without junction) between `GRETZ_OUT` and `GND`. I've move `net names GND` and now is ok:
[image: Net names moved]